# Rails handling .Erb with Nils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

keeps giving me grief when profile is nil... what can i do?

Comment: removed salutation: "Thanks in advance!", don't do it next time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work, too

```
<%= image_tag(this.profile.expiring_url(180)) rescue "no image!" %>
```

Answer (score 7):

Always check if a variable is `nil` before using it in a view.

```
<% image_tag this.profile.expiring_url(180) unless this.profile.nil? %>
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution to the problem, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

First you'd need to decide what you want to do when there is no profile. Do you want to display a default image? No image at all?

Assuming you wanted to display a default image, you could add a method to your helper:

```
def expiration_url_for( profile )
  (profile && profile.expiring_url(180)) || default_url
end
```

and then call that helper method in your view:

```
<%=image_tag expiration_url_for( this.profile )%>
```